# Re-encrypting the encrypted data file generates a decrypted output

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

I wrote the encryption function using Crypto++ library, function behaves correctly when a file encryption is done for the first time. If the same encrypted file is passed again for encryption, generates the output which includes encrypted and decrypted data.

```
bool EncryptDataFile(const char* inputFile, const char* outputFile)
{
  try
  {
    std::vector<byte> key = HexDecoding(PASSCODE);
    std::vector<byte> iv = HexDecoding(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);

    GCM<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), iv.data(), iv.size());

    FileSource fs(inputFile, true,
        new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,
            new FileSink(outputFile), false, TAG_SIZE));
  }

  catch(...)
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Input.txt:

```
Privacy and Security
```

Output1.txt - first time encryption output:

```
{)ªei ?ñìCzN[hç&Ää€|Ùrñ½…
Ä
```

Input "Output1.txt", Output "Output2.txt" - second time encryption:

```
Privacy and Security]®Ÿwþñ úeS„£Fpä40WL ,ÈR¯M
```

It has revealed the original data. An not sure what is missing here.

Comment: Also see [Multiple encryption](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/02/02/multiple-encryption/) on Matthew Green's blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the same encrypted file is passed again for encryption, generates the output which includes encrypted and decrypted data.

If I am parsing things correctly, you are saying `m ≅ Enc(Enc(m))` instead of `c = Enc(Enc(m))` in your encryption scheme. This is one of the reasons why you should avoid designing your own scheme.

This can happen in several scenarios, like with a stream cipher or block cipher in counter mode when re-using a key and iv.

You should using a different security context for each message or encryption operation. With some hand waiving, that means change the key or iv for each message or encryption operation.

---

> ```
> std::vector<byte> key = HexDecoding(PASSCODE);
> std::vector<byte> iv = HexDecoding(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);
> ```

This is likely your problem. You need to use a different security context for each message or encryption operation.

---

Here is how you fix it. You use a key derivation function to derive different security parameters for each encryption. In the code below, the 32-byte key is divided into two 16-byte keys. The same applies to the iv. The first encryption uses `key+0` and `iv+0`; and the second encryption uses `key+16` and `iv+16`.

```cxx
cryptopp$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "gcm.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "hkdf.h"
#include "sha.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    std::string password = "super secret password";
    SecByteBlock key(32), iv(32);

    HKDF<SHA256> hkdf;
    hkdf.DeriveKey(key, key.size(),
                   (const byte*)password.data(), password.size(),
                   NULL, 0,  // salt
                   (const byte*)"key derivation", 14);

    hkdf.DeriveKey(iv, iv.size(),
                   (const byte*)password.data(), password.size(),
                   NULL, 0,  // salt
                   (const byte*)"iv derivation", 13);


    std::string m = "Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.";
    std::string c1, c2;

    GCM<AES>::Encryption encryptor;

    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, 16, iv, 16);
    StringSource(m, true, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(
                 encryptor, new StringSink(c1)));

    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key+16, 16, iv+16, 16);
    StringSource(c1, true, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(
                 encryptor, new StringSink(c2)));    

    std::cout << "Hex(m):" << std::endl;
    StringSource(m, true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hex(Enc(m)):" << std::endl;
    StringSource(c1, true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hex(Enc(Enc(m))):" << std::endl;
    StringSource(c2, true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a run of the program:

```
cryptopp$ ./test.exe
Hex(m):
596F646120736169642C20446F206F7220646F206E6F742E205468657265206973206E6F20747279
2E
Hex(Enc(m)):
D4A9063DE7400E90627DE90D16346DC5A99740C55F6FEE092A99071F55F1BDB25A72B7422126CCC4
09B5B5C0076E39EBF7256D5DC3151A738D
Hex(Enc(Enc(m))):
83A459F2D4A1627624AF162590465AC705C8AC0F4D915E4A4A9D300156C5F9E042CAA47903353F0A
A1FAE408D5747DD223AC4F9AEF3C320EEF7E79E08AB2C6FBEAE7A3A5B4978C45C7
```

---

I think your scheme has some additional problems. For example, if you encrypt the message *"Attack at dawn!"* multiple times, then you get the same ciphertext on each run. It is leaking information, and it lacks ciphertext indistinguishability.

I think you should avoid your scheme, and use an [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). It avoids most of the latent problems in your scheme, and achieves [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IND-CCA2).

The downside to ECIES is, you have to manage a public/private keypair. It is not a big downside, though. You are already managing a password and iv, so changing from a password to a private key is not much more work.

Comment: Okay if i derive the key and iv as shown above, how to decrypt the message. Also please suggest a good reference for understanding cryptography. Thank you

Comment: To decrypt you would use `GCM<AES>::Decryption`, `AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter`, `key+16` and `iv+16` first, then `key+0` and `iv+0` second. The Crypto++ wiki has a list of books at [Recommended Books](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Recommended_Books).